# setInterval - wait longer on first element for each loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

I have an image slideshow that I am doing using `setInterval`. I would like it to hold for 5s on the first item, and then 1s on the additional items each time it loops. Here's what I tried:

```js
let current = 0,
    delay = 5000;
    
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
    }
    current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
    console.log(current);
    if (current === 0) {
        delay = 5000;
    } else {
        delay = 1000;
    }
    slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
}, delay);
```

```css
.slider {
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
}
  .slider img {
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
  }
    .slider img + img {
      opacity:0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Hold 5 Seconds" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/0000FF/808080?text=Hold 1 Second" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=Hold 1 Second" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/000000/FFFFFF?text=Hold 1 Second" />
</div>
```

This does not seem to work, I'm guessing because once the `setInterval` delay has been set, it cannot be changed. So how would I go about making it so that the first image shows for 5s, the next 3 show for 1s and then back to 5s on the first image?

Comment: I guess, the problem is that setInterval with a value of 5000 for 'delay' is defined before the function (which changes the value for delay) is executed. Changing the value 'delay' within the function has no effect on the setInterval statement any more. You should have a function for the first call with setTimeout(..., 5000), which then calls a second function with setInterval(..., 1000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeOut for that. I keep almost of your code so that you can understand.

```js
let current = 0,
    delay = 5000;
    
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
function showNextSlide() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }

  slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
  if (current === 0) {
    delay = 5000;
  } else {
    delay = 1000;
  }
  
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
  setTimeout(showNextSlide, delay);
}


showNextSlide();
```

```css
.slider {
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
}
  .slider img {
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
  }
    .slider img + img {
      opacity:0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Hold 5 Seconds" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/0000FF/808080?text=Hold 1 Second" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=Hold 1 Second" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/000000/FFFFFF?text=Hold 1 Second" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not change the interval by that way. It repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. Updating the interval you have to clear and create new one with new delay time as the example below. But I think you might have to try to use the setTimeOut instead.

```
let current = 0,
delay = 5000, nIntervId = null;
    
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');

changeTheSlideItem = function(){
     for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
    }
    current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
    console.log(current);
    if (current === 0) {
        delay = 5000;
    } else {
        delay = 1000;
    }
    slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
    if(nIntervId){
      clearInterval(nIntervId);
    }
    nIntervId = setInterval(changeTheSlideItem, delay);
}

nIntervId = setInterval(changeTheSlideItem, delay);
```